# I'm unable to fetch analytics data

Tags: laravel, google-analytics, laravel-blade, analytics

I'm trying to fetch the analytics view count dat. After rendering my web page to each user, it saves the view count to the database, which I can fetch. Also, I want to reduce its time to 2 days maximum.

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $analyticsData = Analytics::fetchVisitorsAndPageViews(Period::days(7));
    $analyticsData = Analytics::fetchMostVisitedPages(Period::days(1));

    $google_count = array();
    $filter = $request->filter ?? null;

    $parent = Category::where('job', '1')->pluck('id')->toArray();

    $cat = Category::where('job', '0')
        ->where('status', '1')
        ->whereNotIn('parent', $parent)
        ->orderBy('order', 'asc')
        ->get();

    $pageViews = [];

    foreach ($factory as $fact) {
        $analyticsData = Analytics::fetchVisitorsAndPageViews(Period::days(1));

        $days = 30;
        $analyticsData = Analytics::performQuery(
            Period::days($days),
            'ga:pageviews',
            [
                'dimensions' => 'ga:pagePath',
                'filters' => "ga:pagePath==/factory/{$fact->slug}",
            ]
        );

        $pageViews[$fact->slug] = $analyticsData['totalsForAllResults']['ga:pageviews'];
    }
}
```